Decryption with approximate key
I was thinking about an encryption based solely on biometric data, without any storage or communication.
Let us say that two readings are considered of the same person if $d(x,y) \le \varepsilon$ for some unspecified metric $d$ and threshold $\varepsilon$.
Are there any known cryptosystems with this property, where $\operatorname{Decrypt}_y(\operatorname{Encrypt}_x(m)) = m$ for $d(x,y)\le \varepsilon$ in some metric, but it is still secure otherwise?

This has been asked and answered on our sister site. A similar if not identical question is to calculate a cryptographic hash over the fingerprint. A lot of research went into this subject, even much earlier than the Q on that site (the Vrije Universiteit looked at it before I know for sure as I visited them after I studied there). But I haven't heard too much about it afterwards; generally you'd instead use the fingerprint to unlock keys, and for that you'd only have to have a 1:1 match.

This feels unlikely other than for boring metrics or very unusual characteristics. You are asking for your metric to behave in a "stronger than triangle" inequality own your space of feature values. Specifically, you need that if $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ and $d(y,z)<\epsilon$ then $d(x,z)<\epsilon$ (i.e. if feature value $x$ is similar to $y$ and $y$ is similar to $z$ then $x$ is similar to $z$). This is true for the rather boring discrete metric, but not very helpful. Unless your feature values are very strongly clustered under the metric, it's likely that either each feature value has its own key or that all feature values have the same key.
However, if we weaken the requirement so that the property holds "with high probability" in some sense, there might be some hope. For example, if one can map the feature space to a vector in a finite field and one has a large, relatively efficient covering code for that space, one could define the encryption/decryption process as "take the feature value, find a nearest covering codeword, apply a key derivation function to the codeword, use the key in AES encryption/decryption. It won't work universally because some close feature vectors will lie in the covering radius of different codewords, and this should be enough for "high probability".
